# Resize an element (li) by it's edges

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a fiddle with some basic code, please advise on resize functionality, core Javascript ninjas and gurus

http://jsfiddle.net/developer11/ZGTL3/

```
<div id="bars">
<ul id="bars_3">
<li id="bars_3_0"><a id="resizer" href="javascript:;"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript is

```
document.getElementById("bars_3_0").firstChild.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
event.preventDefault();
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveHandler);
}, false);

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveHandler);   
});

function mousemoveHandler() {
console.log('move');   
}
```

Comment: Try use jquery plugins

Comment: +1 for that suggestion

Comment: I looked up http://jqueryui.com/resizable/ but it resizes horizontally and vertically, and then I need to retrieve the size of the barchart value and update (not required in this solution) but I want this basic resize functionality in core javascript

Comment: If you found your answer here, could you please mark it as your accepted answer? If you did it in another way then you should answer your own question and accept that for the benefit other developers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a flag to true on `mousedown` and set it to false on `mouseup`. Then on `mousemove` you can change the hight or position of your element to match the current mouse position.

In your `mousemove` listener you can check your `mousedown` flag to see if you should update the position or not.

[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MouseEvent) might help you get started.

Comment: I did some updates based on what I can think, also notice after I press mouse down, and drag, the cursor changes into not-allowed "circle with cross" symbol

Comment: yes this page would definitely be helpful but I'm now concerned with this not-allowed cursor symbol and the mousemoveHandler functions stopped getting called (see console please)

Comment: update: event.preventDefault(); removed the not-allowed symbol

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("bars_3_0").firstChild.onmousedown = function() {
        console.log('down');
    };
```

Hope this solves your problem in the fiddler code.

```
document.getElementById("bars_3_0").firstChild.onmousedown=function() {
document.onmousemove=mousemoveHandler
};

document.onmouseup=function() {
document.onmousemove='';   
};

function mousemoveHandler() {
console.log('move');   
}
```

Comment: thanks we're progressing, the not-allowed symbol issue was resolved by event.preventDefault on mousedown, fiddler updated. any suggestion for resizing stuff, I'm also thinking